# How to know what to write to pull through a product attribute Magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes, php-7, object

Please excuse my ignorance as PHP 7 is completely new to me.

The more and more I work with Magento 2 the more I'm understanding objects.
But my question is:

You have objects the their contents such as:

```
$block->getFramePages()
```

or

```
$_product->getProductUrl()
```

as examples.

If I was to create a new attribute for a product say "Ready to go" answers "Yes"/"No"

How would I know how to pull it through to the page. What would be its equivilant to getFramesPages() for example?

Answer (score 2):

The attribute names are in snake case: `ready_to_go`. To use the magic getter and setter methods, convert to camel case: `$model->getReadyToGo`. This is shorthand for `$model->getData('ready_to_go')`. This feature is implemented by Magento, it's not related to php7.